# How can I change the collapse direction of cflayoutarea without including JS/bootstrap?

Tags: layout, coldfusion

I'm trying to add a collapse option to a CF report that can sometimes print out a long list. I can collapse it using `<cflayout>` and `<cflayoutarea>`. However, it will only collapse to the left. I would like it to collapse upwards.

I've tried different layout types but cannot find a way to change the direction it collapses in.

```
<cflayout type="border" height="500"> 
    <cflayoutarea title="Related IPs" position="left" collapsible="true" style="width:300px;">
        <cfif qAddress.match>
            <strong>From same IP address</strong><br>
        </cfif>
    </cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
```

Comment: If this is a new implementation of `cflayout`, I would replace it with jQuery UI or something else. Those CF UI libraries are way outdated and difficult to change their behavior.

Comment: ... which is why they've have fallen out of favor. They're okay for really basic stuff, but trying to customize is often .. painful.  If you really can't update, try looking in the old sencha ExtJS docs to see if such a thing was even possible back in 4.1. I think that's the version CF2016+ use..

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using? Also, like everyone else is saying, I would replace it with a newer. UI library

Comment: I was recvently surprised to see, ACF 2018 comes with Ext JS 6.6.0.258

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - You're right about 2018. How odd... I was going by cffiddle.org which shows Ext JS 4.1 for *CF2018 Update 4*, in ext-all.js - but the same version on my local machine says Ext JS 6.6.0.258 .

Comment: Unsure of the version, as I'm working in someone else's repo. Thanks for the input though, everyone. Sounds like it'll take a little extra legwork

Comment: To view the version info `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`